# Json content for One post in Many to one rs request in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, mapping

So i have two classes,
class User:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String displayName;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    private String Nationality;
    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Event> createdEvents;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Reservation> clientReservations;


}
```

and class Event:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String eventName;
    private Date eventDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

Contoller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/event")
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Event addEvent(@RequestBody Event event) {
        return eventRepository.save(event);
    }
}
```

Json:

```
"eventName": "theatre",
    "eventDate": "2020-04-22",
    "user": 3
```

im new to spring boot and what I've tried doesn't work.
now i want to add a single Event, and i need to pass a  user id to reference the user who created the event, How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**
In your Event class, add a constructor like this:

```
public Event(String eventName, Date eventDate, User user) {
    this.createdAt = new DateTime();
    
    this.eventName = eventName;
    this.eventDate = eventDate;
    this.user = user;
}
```

**2.**
Instead of passing `Event` as `@RequestBody`, consider creating a dto that handles submitted data on Post requests

```
public class EventDto {
    private String eventName;
    private String eventDateString;
    private Long userId;

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getEventDateString() {
        return eventDateString;
    }

    public void setEventDateString(String eventDateString) {
        this.eventDateString = eventDateString;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Then you must replace `@RequestBody Event event` with `@RequestBody EventDto eventDto`

**3.**
Inject `UserRepository`, handle data, check that submitted user id exists and save your Event

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public Event addEvent(@RequestBody EventDto eventDto) throws ParseException {
    var user = userRepository.findById(eventDto.getUserId());

    if (user.isPresent()) {
        Event event = new Event(eventDto.eventName.trim(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(eventDto.eventDateString), user.get());
        eventRepository.save(event);
    }
}
```